# Constrain logic in Linear programming

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, stochastic

I'm trying to build a linear optimization model for a production unit. I have Decision variable (binary variable) X(i)(j) where I is hour of J day. The constrain I need to introduce is a limitation on downtime (minimum time period the production unit needs to be turned off between two starts).

For example:

```
Hours:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
On/off: 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1  0  0  1
```

I cannot run the hour 4 or 7 because time period between 2 and 4 / 5 and 7 is one. I can run hour 12 since I have two hour gap after hour 9. How do I enforce this constrain in Linear programming/ optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for a way to model: "*at least two consecutive periods of **down time***". A simple formulation is to **forbid** the pattern:

```
t  t+1 t+2
1   0   1
```

This can be written as a linear inequality:

```
x(t) - x(t+1) + x(t+2) <= 1
```

---

One way to convince yourself this is correct is to just enumerate the patterns:

```
x(t)  x(t+1) x(t+2)  LHS
 0      0      0      0 
 0      0      1      1
 0      1      0     -1
 0      1      1      0
 1      0      0      1
 1      0      1      2  <--- to be excluded 
 1      1      0      0 
 1      1      1      1
```

With `x(t) - x(t+1) + x(t+2) <= 1` we exactly exclude the pattern `101` but allow all others.

---

Similarly, "*at least two consecutive periods of **up time***" can be handled by excluding the pattern

```
t  t+1 t+2
0   1   0
```

or

```
-x(t) + x(t+1) - x(t+2) <= 0
```

---

Note: one way to derive the second from the first constraint is to observe that forbidding the pattern `010` is the same as saying `y(t)=1-x(t)` and excluding `101` in terms of `y(t)`. In other words:

```
(1-x(t)) - (1-x(t+1)) + (1-x(t+2)) <= 1
```

This is identical to

```
-x(t) + x(t+1) - x(t+2) <= 0
```

In the comments it is argued this method does not work. That is based on a substantial misunderstanding of this method. The pattern 100 (i.e. `x(1)=1,x(2)=0,x(3)=0`) is not allowed because

```
 -x(0)+x(1)-x(2) <= 0
```

Where `x(0)` is the status before we start our planning period. This is historic data. If `x(0)=0` we have `x(1)-x(2)<=0`, disallowing 10. I.e. this method is correct (if not, a lot of my models would fail).

Comment: Thank you. That helped. Just an extension of the query and curious to know how do you model "at least two consecutive periods of running"?

Comment: That can be modeled in a very similar way.

Comment: Good explanation. I think this answer should be accepted. Maybe the intuition behind the first inequality is clearer starting with `x(t) + (1 - x(t+1)) + x(t+2) <= 2` (_not all three_), which is then simplified to `x(t) - x(t+1) + x(t+2) <= 1`?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, the given logic for **up time** fails in 3 states. `1 0 0, 0 0 1 and 1 0 1` in all these cases **LHS** is `<=0`, but they don't have **two consecutive up time**.

Comment: Border thing. This depends on the state at x(0) and x(T+1). These cases need to be handled accordingly.